# How to remove some part from String from Pandas

Tags: pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby, data-analysis, exploratory-data-analysis

**I only want the Month from this Column and want to drop all the rest of the values how do I do that. Have checked all then StackOverFlow other questions nothing seems top work.
Can someone please help me out :D**

[image: ** **]

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a datetime object, but if not you'll want to convert it to one with:

```
df['created_at']= pd.to_datetime(df['created_at'])
```

Once it's a datetime object, you can create a month column with the following:

```
df['month'] = df['created_at'].dt.month
```